# Practical applications of disjoint set datastructure

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

I know that the disjoint set datastructure is used   to keep track of the connected components of an undirected graph when the edges are added to the graph dynamically . I also know that is is used in [Kruskal's  algorithm for minimum spanning trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) . What are the other possible applications of this datastructure ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Maze generation (using a modified Kruskal's algorithm)
- [Tarjan's off-line least common ancestors algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_off-line_least_common_ancestors_algorithm)
- Connected component labeling
- Online maintenance of biconnected components
- [Validation Hindley–Milner rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner#Degrees_of_freedom_instantiating_the_rules)
- Computing the winner of [Havannah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havannah) board game (see [Efficient Playouts for the
  Havannah Abstract Board Game](http://www.imn.htwk-leipzig.de/~waldmann/draft/havannah/main.pdf))
- Alias analysis
- Used in construction of contour trees (see [Laying the Foundations for an Advanced
  Visualization System in O'Caml](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/files/viz.pdf) and [Multi-Resolution computation and presentation of Contour Trees](http://www.pascucci.org/pdf-papers/orrery-2005.pdf))